# Function not attaching to wp_footer hook

Tags: wordpress, action, hook

I'm having some issues getting this functionality to work. It must be something I'm overlooking. This is my code:

```
if ( is_page_template('template-thankyou.php') ) {
    function eh_add_product_tracking_code(){
        $meta_key = 'product_code';
        $meta_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $meta_key, true);

        return $meta_value;
    }

    add_action('wp_footer', 'eh_add_product_tracking_code');
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to add a custom field named `product_code` to the footer of the **template-thankyou.php** page from the **functions.php** file within WordPress.

As you can see, I check to see if we are on a page using the correct template. Then I use a function to get the custom field text and return it. Then I add it to the footer.

The footer shows nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

add **global $post;** in the beginning of your function.

The $post variable you are using in get_post_meta() is not pointing to the post.

Comment: Thank for catching that. I added the the global $post; with no dice. This will most likely help. http://www.learnwebdevelopment.com/crazy/ is the page I'm working on.